# Android Studio - cannot create a new directory in android studio

Tags: android-studio

```
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    
File storageDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                  Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) 
                  + File.separator + "/MyCamera");
Log.d("PATH", storageDir.getAbsolutePath());

boolean success = true;
if (!storageDir.exists()) {
    success = storageDir.mkdirs();
    Log.d("MAKE DIR", storageDir.mkdirs() + "");
    System.out.println("    "+imageFileName);
}

// Save the new Bitmap
if (success) {
    ....................
}
```

this is the code to create a new directory in the path given
but it does not create a new one

- D/PATH: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/MyCamera
- D/MAKE DIR: false
- I/System.out:     JPEG_20210406_051715.jpg

  > ```
  > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  > <uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.CAMERA" android:required="true" />
  > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  > <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
  > ```

But I don't know why it could not create the folder. I also used mkdir() as well as mkdirs() but the result is the same.

Comment: is your user giving you a permission through permission dialogs?

Comment: To access the storage? No dialog box opens up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File fileName = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "FILENAME");

if (!fileName.exists())
fileName.createNewFile();

Comment: Please give vote if answer is useful in file creation.